# SOQL : View details of CronTrigger.CronJobDetail.Name

Tags: apex, soql

I am trying to run this query to get the details of the Apex class for scheduled jobs.

```
SELECT ApexClassId,Id,JobItemsProcessed,JobType,Status,NumberOfErrors,MethodName,CronTrigger.CronJobDetail.Name FROM AsyncApexJob where JobType in ('BatchApexWorker','ScheduledApex')
```

This query gives me an error while running in XL connector App as shown below

[image]

But the same query does not give me any error when run from the console as shown below

[image]

**Questions**

a) Can someone tell me why the same query gives error in XL connector tool while working fine in Query Editor in Dev Console ?

b) Even if it is working in Dev Console, I am still not able to view the details of the `CronTrigger.CronJobDetail.Name` as it just shows "object" eventhough I have mentioned it as `CronTrigger.CronJobDetail.Name` ...Can someone let me know why ?

Comment: First, check that both users have the required CRUD/FLS permissions. Second, why are you looking for BatchApexWorker jobs? These are internal.

Comment: Both of them were executed with my login which has CRUD/FLS

Comment: The screenshot shows you using `CronTrigger.CronJobDetail` instead of `CronTrigger.CronJobDetail.Name`. The `CronJobDetail` IS a form of object, and gets rendered as that object in the UI (via JavaScript by the looks of it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you why the XL Connector can't handle the query. Maybe it's running too low of an API version or something. You'd have to get in touch with the appropriate tech support.

As far as the second problem, `[object Object]` is what happens when you call `toString` on an object in JavaScript. The Developer Console was not designed to handle nested child or parent relationships. Consequently, it can only go "down" or "up" one level. I've complained about this limitation before, but I don't know if it will ever be fixed, since most tooling effort is dedicated to the VS Code/SF CLI tools.

Consider using VS Code or the SF CLI. These programs will correctly output multilevel relationships.